# Correctly interpret Butterworth filter frequencies

Tags: r, filter, signal-processing, fft, butterworth

I am using the `butter` function from the `signal` package in R to filter my data.

The data is Fourier-transformed (complex numbers) - and I want to filter out specific frequencies (I have a 256Hz sampling frequency, hence a 128Hz spectrum and say I want to filter only data from 4-8Hz).

I find conflicting documentation on what the correct values for W in this function should be:

```
butter(n, W, type = c("low", "high", "stop", "pass"),
plane = c("z", "s"), ...)
```

- should they be 4/256 and 8/256?

I find it hard to interpret whether my results with 4/256 and 8/256 are correct.

```
strength <- ftdata
low <- 4
high <- 8
bf <- butter(5, low/256, type="high")
bfsig <- filter(bf, strength)
bf <- butter(5, high/256, type="low")
bfsig <- filter(bf, bfsig)

plot(f,bfsig, type='l')

# Where ftdata is just the output from my Fourier transform. The 5 is the order of the filter.
```

I just want to know whether the "/256" makes sense here.

EDIT:

Also, any idea why the below does not return the same result as the above?

```
 filt <- butter(5,c(low/256,high/256), "pass")
 bfsig <- filter(filt, strength)
```

It should just be a combination of the low and high-pass filters.

Answer (score 0):

In DSP, frequency is treated as "Normalized frequency". Normalized frequency is calculated by scaling frequency range 0 to smapling frequency into 0 to 1.0 . So you have to divide specific frequencies by 256.

Comment: Thank you - so do you agree that the above code correctly filters the signal such that only the components between 4-8Hz remain?

Comment: I checked the reference of [butter](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/signal/versions/0.7-6/topics/butter). I found that it says "For digital filters, W must be between 0 and 1 where 1 is the Nyquist frequency.". So I think you have to divide specific frequencies by 128 such as 4 / 128 and 8 / 128. And you can check the frequency response of your filter by using freqz. Please try it.

Comment: And I have a question about your filter input signal. You said that it was Fourier-transformed. But Butterworth filters are applied to time-domain signals in general as long as I know. Do you want to really apply it to frequency-domain signals?

Comment: Agreed now - I think 128 should be right. Yes it should help to extract the signal between 2 frequency bands right? If I then inverse FT the signal, it should give me the cleaned time signal.

Comment: If you apply this filter to a signal in time-domain, you will get given band eliminated signal.